# Prefix support in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, prefix, sequelize.js

Is there any way to support prefixed tables names when using Sequelize.js ?

Imagine I wanted to build a blogging platform so that each registered user would get his own blog and URL (subdomain).
Now if one opens `userxxx.mydomain.com` he should get content from tables named `userxxx_TABLENAME` while opening `difuser.mydomain.com` would fetch data from `difuser_TABLENAME` etc.

I tried adding prefixes to models names eg: `sequelize.define('userxxx_Post' ...)` which could work but creates mess when it comes to many-to-many relations (table names become `userxxx_Postuserxxx_Comment`).

Is there any better way?

(I'm not exactly building a blogging platform on node.js but solution to this problem will be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `tableName` option?

[From docs](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/models#block-14-line-19)